# Extended AutoCorrelation Function

Tags: functions, packages, time-series

Is there a function in Mathematica capable of computing the sample Extended AutoCorrelation Function (EACF)?

I know that there's a package in R that does this. I was trying to avoid to having to programme it from scratch, or having to call the R function.

[Here's](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/ruey.tsay/teaching/bs41910/lec9.pdf) an explanation by one of the authors of this measure. See page 4.

This measure is basically used to choose the numbers $p,q$ in an ARMA($p,q$).

Comment: Calling R functions are not so difficult using RLink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, the answer to your question is simply: no.

---

#### Meta comments:

I don't think your question ought to be closed as "out of scope", since you are not actually asking for anyone to write the function for you.

My suggestion would be to write the function yourself and edit the question to include your attempt, making the focus of the revised question be on suggestions for how it could be improved. By doing so, you are likely to get more optimized or more general versions without having to invest all of the effort yourself.

Alternatively, delete this question and ask a new one along those lines.